# dollar curly brackets issue in JSP and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-templates

In JSP, I notice that I can't render ${} into HTML. After the page is rendered, the HTML page will not show ${} anymore. In my understanding, ${} is part of java syntax.

Is there any approach to render this into HTML? Currently, I use print "${}" as a string so I can render this on my HTML. I need this symbol to be rendered as it is so later I can grab this symbol using jquery. (FYI: I'm using jquery template)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\${this is not an EL expression}
```

Escape the expression with `\` if it appears in a JSP template.

From the [JSP EL 2.2 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245):

> To generate literal values that include the character sequence `${` or
>   `#{`, the developer can choose to use a composite expression as shown
>   here:
>
> ```
> ${'${'}exprA}
> #{'#{'}exprB}
> ```
>
> The resulting values would then be the strings `${exprA}` and
>   `#{exprB}`.
>
> Alternatively, the escape characters `\$` and `\#` can be used to
>   escape what would otherwise be treated as an eval-expression. Given
>   the literal-expressions:
>
> ```
> \${exprA}
> \#{exprB}
> ```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You have to add JSF to the header. 
I had to escape javascript string substitution with parameter inside JSF xhtml page, so it will not be treated as EL expression.

Comment: In `<img src="{% static '${fname}' %}"` if I want to escape the outer {}, how to do it? `${fname}` is not being interpreted as a variable because of these outer curly braces. Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \${expression}. If you are not using EL in that JSP page. then you can use
<%@ page isELIgnored ="true" %>.

I would recommend you to use **\${expression}** and use the EL in other part of JSP. EL is very powerful and very helpful.

~Rajiv

Answer (score 1):

Put this line at the top of your JSP.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="true" %>
```